# How to run asynchronous methods or commands from synchronous UI events methods in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have a `MainPage` with a `ViewModel` that, when a button is clicked, executes a command in the `ViewModel` that navigates the user, by the shell navigation methods, to a new `ContentPage`. When this navigation is completed, I want to execute a method from the second `ContentPage`'s `ViewModel`.

I'm trying to do it by overriding the `OnNavigatedTo` method of the second `ContentPage` and, from there, calling the method or command on its `ViewModel` but the command or method to call is asynchronous and the `OnNavigatedTo` method is synchronous, so how to call the asynchronous method without having problems with the UI and application asynchronous flow?

Lets take as an example a `ContentPage` class that is going to be our `MainPage`:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    private readonly MainPageViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainPage(MainPageViewModel mainPageViewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = mainPageViewModel;
        BindingContext = _viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
}
```

and its `ViewModel`:

```
public partial class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    //Consider that this method is a Command and is binded to a button click
    public async Task GoToOtherPage() {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(OtherPage));
    }
}
```

On the other side there is an `OtherPage`:

```
public partial class OtherPage : ContentPage
{

    private readonly OtherPageViewModel _viewModel;

    public OtherPage(OtherPageViewModel otherPageViewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = otherPageViewModel;
        BindingContext = _viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and its `ViewModel`:

```
public partial class OtherPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    //This is the asynchronous method to be called when the user navigates to this page
    public async Task OnNavigatedTo() 
    {
        //Do something asynchronously
    }
}
```

I have tried to call it by overriding the `OnNavigatedTo` method of the `OtherPage` that way:

```
public partial class OtherPage : ContentPage
{

    private readonly OtherPageViewModel _viewModel;

    public OtherPage(OtherPageViewModel otherPageViewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = otherPageViewModel;
        BindingContext = _viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override void OnNavigatedTo()
    {
        _viewModel.OnNavigatedTo().Wait();
    }
}
```

but the application runs through a break state. What can I do?

Comment: Have you _tried_ making it `public override async void OnNavigatedTo` and await the async call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you just need to call the asynchronous operation using the [Dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.dispatching.dispatcher?view=net-maui-7.0).

Example:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
    Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(async () =>
    {
        await _viewModel.OnNavigatedTo();
    });
}
```

This will dispatch the operation through the UI thread and is not going to block the application.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method named OnNavigatedTo without any parameter can be overrided in the ContentPage. It should have a NavigatedToEventArgs as parameter:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
    await _viewModel.OnNavigatedTo();
}
```

Note: When you try to override a method, you can input the `override` keywords and the visual studio will prompt you and auto complete the method after you select the method you want to override.

In addition, you can also try to override the `OnAppearing` method instead of the `OnNavigatedTo` method